# C++ Primer fifth edtion book (if statement) is this not correct?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int currVal = 0, val = 0;

    if (std::cin >> currVal) {
        int cnt = 1; 

        while (std::cin >> val) { 
            if (val == currVal)
                ++cnt; 
            else 
            {
                std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
                currVal = val; 
                cnt = 1; 
            }
        } 

        std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

If we give this program the following input:

> 42 42 42 42 42 55 55 62 100 100 100

then the output should be

> 42 occurs 5 times
>
> 55 occurs 2 times
>
> 62 occurs 1 times
>
> 100 occurs 3 times

All this code should work properly. Sorry for the inconvenience.(had a brain fart)

Comment: `cin >> x` used as a condition will be false if the read fails, which is really important in making sure you only act on good input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [appears to work as expected](http://ideone.com/oDmDvM).

There is a very good reason to do `std::cin >> whatever` in the condition of an `if` statement or `while` loop. The extraction operator `>>` returns the stream that you're operating on. So the value of the `std::cin >> whatever` expression is `std::cin` itself.

A stream, such as `std::cin`, can be converted to `bool` for the sake of checking whether the stream is in a valid state. Consider:

```
if (std::cin >> whatever)
```

This can be understood as taking input from the user into the variable `whatever` and then checking if the input was valid or not. If not, the `if` block will not execute.

Similarly:

```
while (std::cin >> whatever)
```

This will loop, taking input from the user each time, until the user enters something invalid.

What is an invalid input? Well if `whatever` in the above examples was an `int`, and the user entered the text `blah`, this would fail because it's not a valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given works as intended.

The expression `stream >> variable` produces a reference to the `stream`, and as an `if` condition this is then converted to `bool` *as if* you had written `!(stream >> variable).fail()`.

However, while the code works technically, it has much redundancy

And so, except if the author’s point was to illustrate technically ungood code (perhaps with a discussion of all that’s wrong with it) it’s ungood pedagogically.

Here is an alternative formulation with much less redundancy:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int current_value = 0;
    int run_length = 0;

    for( bool at_end = false; !at_end; )
    {
        int value;
        at_end = (cin >> value).fail();

        if( run_length > 0 && (at_end || value != current_value) )
        {
            cout << current_value << " occurs " << run_length << " times" << endl;
            run_length = 0;
        }

        if( !at_end )
        {
            if( run_length == 0 )
            {
                current_value = value;
            }
            ++run_length;
        }
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
[D:\dev\test]
> g++ foo.cpp

[D:\dev\test]
> echo 42 42 42 42 42 55 55 62 100 100 100 | a
42 occurs 5 times
55 occurs 2 times
62 occurs 1 times
100 occurs 3 times

[D:\dev\test]
> _
```