# C++ primer 5th 1.4.4

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner of C++,while reading the book 《C++ Primer》 5th,I'm a little confused in chapter 1.4.4.
when I run the program in 1.4.4,here is the step in my computer:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    // currVal is the number we're counting; we'll read new values into val
    int currVal = 0, val = 0;

    // read first number and ensure that we have data to process
    if (std::cin >> currVal) 
    {
        int cnt = 1;  // store the count for the current value we're processing

        while (std::cin >> val) 
        { // read the remaining numbers

            if (val == currVal)   // if the values are the same
                ++cnt;            // add 1 to cnt
            else 
            { // otherwise, print the count for the previous value
                std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
                currVal = val;    // remember the new value
                cnt = 1;          // reset the counter
            }

        }  // while loop ends here

        // remember to print the count for the last value in the file
        std::cout << currVal <<  " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
    } // outermost if statement ends here

    return 0;
}
```

1. type the numbers:42 42 42 42 42 55 55 62 100 100 100
2. type `Ctrl+D`
3. the program run by itself(not waitting me to input Enter)
4. output the answer:

> 42 occurs 5 times
>   55 occurs 2 times
>   62 occurs 1 times

5. secondly type `Ctrl+D`
6. output the remained answer

   > 100 occurs 3 times

my question is why I have to input second times of Ctrl+D,my code environment is Ubuntu+GCC,I also run it in VS2013,it only needs to input once Ctrl+D.

I've searched in stackoverflow,but I didn't got my answer.

[Incorrect output. C++ primer 1.4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601122/incorrect-output-c-primer-1-4-4)

[confused by control flow execution in C++ Primer example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658499/confused-by-control-flow-execution-in-c-primer-example?lq=1)

[C++ Primer fifth edtion book (if statement) is this not correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188304/c-primer-fifth-edtion-book-if-statement-is-this-not-correct?lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

In Linux `Ctrl+D` does not unconditionally mean "end-of-file" (EOF). What it actually means is "push the currently pending input to whoever is waiting to read it". If the input buffer in non-empty, then hitting `Ctrl+D` *does not* create EOF condition at the end of the buffer. Only if you hit `Ctrl+D` when the input buffer is *empty*, only then it will produce EOF condition. (See here for a more technical explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1516177/187690)

In your case you are inputting your data as a single line and then hitting `Ctrl+D` at the end. This pushes your input to your program and makes your program to read and process the data. But it does not produce EOF condition at the end of your input.

For this reason, once all input data is read by the cycle, your program does not see it as EOF. The cycle keeps waiting on empty input buffer for additional data. If at this point you press `Ctrl+D` again, it will be recognized as EOF and your program will exit the cycle and print the last line.

This is why you have to hit `Ctrl+D` twice: the first hit works pretty much as `Enter` key would. And only the second hit creates EOF condition.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the program you have provided was not intended to accept input all at once as you have shown.

The reason it does not provide the output you expect is due to the fact that the program is still expecting input, because the >> operation's return value is still logically true/error-free. (It's blocked at: `while (std::cin >> val)`) This is so, because you have not provided an EOF to the input stream after the last 100. Said another way, your first `Ctrl+D` gets past the `if (std::cin >> currVal)`. Your second `Ctrl+D` gets past the `while (std::cin >> val)`.

See the accepted answer to this question for why the first `Ctrl+D` does not result in a eofbit error on your input stream: [Why do I have to type ctrl-d twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369170/why-do-i-have-to-type-ctrl-d-twice) The bottom line is that `Ctrl+D` does not necessarily mean EOF; it results in a flush of the input stream.

Entering the numbers one at a time would provide the output you expect.

Alternatively, you could provide: 42 42 42 42 42 55 55 62 100 100 100\n.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/